# Not able to find tables on sql tabs

Tags: heroku, uri

I posted URI from heroku to sql tabs to access my database but I noticed my URI is different now and all my database tables are not there. Can anyone help me with this?
I just want all my tables back so I don't have to set them up all over again. And I would like an explantion as to why I have a different URI in Heroku now is the URI supposed to change?

Comment: What is "sql tabs"? In any case, Heroku can change the connection credentials at any time, for any reason. In practice, it doesn't happen frequently. When it does, you need to use the new `DATABASE_URL` value for all connections.